# Error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sqlplus

I am running into a peculiar issue for last few days. Here are the details.

I am trying to install oracle xe client on an EC2 (redhat like) instance. I am doing this using cloudformation provided by aws which basically first starts the instance and then runs all the script that we provide as root user. While installing it prints the following error message :

**case 1 ) when i try to run it using full path -**

```
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**case 2 ) when i run it using sqlplus keyword only**

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

Cloudformation will provision the instance first after starting and then only , i can log into the instance. Now when i log in to the instance sqlplus command works perfectlty without any issue.

When i echo the environment variables etc, i get proper outputs. i also get everything at proper place too. While provisioning i have created multiple users and they can access the sqlplus too without any problem.

Below is the way i am trying to install oracle xe because i had similar requirement.

a) Download Oracle 11.2 XE for Linux 64 in your $HOME

b) Unzip the zip file you get

c) Unpack the content of the rpm file without installing it (we don't need the Oracle RDBMS to be running on the server) and then

```
        mkdir ~/Oracle11XE-binaries
        cd ~/Oracle11XE-binaries

        # extract all the binaries from the RPM (rather than installing the RPM)
        rpm2cpio ../Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm  | cpio -idmv

        sudo mkdir /opt/oracle
        sudo mv u01/app/oracle/product /opt/oracle

        # clean up downloaded and extracted files (they are BIG)
        cd
        rm -rf Disk1 oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip

        echo 'export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
        export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
        export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh

        # source it so it takes effect in the current session
        . /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
        ldconfig
```

I know the issue is pretty common but i am not finding any way out of it.

Below is the output of ldconfig -p  ( if required , but it doesn't contain libsqlplus.so)

```
 libz.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libz.so.1
        libyaml-0.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2
        libxtables.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxtables.so.10
        libxslt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1
        libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
        libxcb.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1
        libxcb-xvmc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xvmc.so.0
        libxcb-xv.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xv.so.0
        libxcb-xtest.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xtest.so.0
        libxcb-xselinux.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xselinux.so.0
        libxcb-xinerama.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xinerama.so.0
        libxcb-xf86dri.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xf86dri.so.0
        libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xfixes.so.0
        libxcb-xevie.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xevie.so.0
        libxcb-sync.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.0
        libxcb-shm.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0
        libxcb-shape.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shape.so.0
        libxcb-screensaver.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-screensaver.so.0
        libxcb-res.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-res.so.0
        libxcb-render.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-render.so.0
        libxcb-record.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-record.so.0
        libxcb-randr.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-randr.so.0
        libxcb-glx.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0
        libxcb-dri2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0
        libxcb-dpms.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dpms.so.0
        libxcb-damage.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-damage.so.0
        libxcb-composite.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxcb-composite.so.0
        libwrap.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libwrap.so.0
        libverto.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libverto.so.0
        libverto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libverto.so
        libverto-k5ev.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libverto-k5ev.so.0
        libverto-k5ev.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libverto-k5ev.so
        libuuid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libuuid.so.1
        libutil.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libutil.so.1
        libutempter.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libutempter.so.0
        libuser.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libuser.so.1
        libungif.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libungif.so.4
        libudev.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libudev.so.0
        libtinfo.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5
        libtic.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libtic.so.5
        libthread_db.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libthread_db.so.1
        libtasn1.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3
        libsysfs.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libsysfs.so.2
        libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
        libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
        libssl.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
        libssh2.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1
        libss.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libss.so.2
        libsqlite3.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
        libsoftokn3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libsoftokn3.so
        libsmime3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
        libslang.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libslang.so.2
        libsepol.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libsepol.so.1
        libselinux.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
        libsasl2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2
        libruby.so.2.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libruby.so.2.0
        librt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/librt.so.1
        librpmsign.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/librpmsign.so.1
        librpmio.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/librpmio.so.3
        librpmbuild.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/librpmbuild.so.3
        librpm.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/librpm.so.3
        libresolv.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libresolv.so.2
        libreadline.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libreadline.so.6
        libp11-kit.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libp11-kit.so.0
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
        libpython2.7.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so
        libpwquality.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpwquality.so.1
        libpthread.so.0 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
        libpth.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpth.so.20
        libpsl.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpsl.so.0
        libproc-3.2.8.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libproc-3.2.8.so
        libpopt.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpopt.so.0
        libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0
        libpng.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpng.so.3
        libplds4.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libplds4.so
        libplc4.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libplc4.so
        libpipeline.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpipeline.so.1
        libpcreposix.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
        libpcrecpp.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
        libpcre.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre.so.0
        libpcprofile.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /usr/lib64/libpcprofile.so
        libpci.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpci.so.3
        libparted-2.1.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libparted-2.1.so.0
        libpanelw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpanelw.so.5
        libpanel.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpanel.so.5
        libpamc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpamc.so.0
        libpam_misc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpam_misc.so.0
        libpam.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpam.so.0
        libopts.so.25 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libopts.so.25
        libopcodes-2.23.52.0.1-16.47.amzn1.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libopcodes-2.23.52.0.1-16.47.amzn1.so
        libnuma.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1
        libnss3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
        libnssutil3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
        libnsssysinit.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnsssysinit.so
        libnsspem.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnsspem.so
        libnssdbm3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnssdbm3.so
        libnssckbi.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnssckbi.so
        libnss_nisplus.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_nisplus.so.2
        libnss_nis.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_nis.so.2
        libnss_hesiod.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_hesiod.so.2
        libnss_files.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_files.so.2
        libnss_dns.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_dns.so.2
        libnss_db.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_db.so.2
        libnss_compat.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnss_compat.so.2
        libnspr4.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnspr4.so
        libnsl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libnsl.so.1
        libnih.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnih.so.1
        libnih-dbus.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libnih-dbus.so.1
        libnewt.so.0.52 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libnewt.so.0.52
        libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libncursesw.so.5
        libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libncurses.so.5
        libmp.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmp.so.3
        libmount.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libmount.so.1
        libmenuw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmenuw.so.5
        libmenu.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmenu.so.5
        libmemusage.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /usr/lib64/libmemusage.so
        libmagic.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmagic.so.1
        libm.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libm.so.6
        liblzma.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5
        liblwres.so.80 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/liblwres.so.80
        liblvm2cmd.so.2.02 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblvm2cmd.so.2.02
        liblvm2app.so.2.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblvm2app.so.2.2
        liblua-5.1.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/liblua-5.1.so
        libldif-2.4.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libldif-2.4.so.2
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
        libldap-2.4.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2
        liblcms2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/liblcms2.so.2
        liblber-2.4.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2
        libk5crypto.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3
        libkrb5support.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0
        libkrb5.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3
        libkmod.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2
        libkeyutils.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1
        libkdb5.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libkdb5.so.6
        libkadm5srv_mit.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libkadm5srv_mit.so.8
        libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8
        libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62
        libisccfg.so.82 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libisccfg.so.82
        libisccc.so.80 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libisccc.so.80
        libisc.so.83 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libisc.so.83
        libip6tc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libip6tc.so.0
        libip4tc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libip4tc.so.0
        libiptc.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libiptc.so.0
        libidn.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libidn.so.11
        libicuuc.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.50
        libicutu.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicutu.so.50
        libicutest.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicutest.so.50
        libiculx.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libiculx.so.50
        libicule.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicule.so.50
        libicui18n.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50
        libicuio.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicuio.so.50
        libicudata.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.50
        libhistory.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libhistory.so.6
        libhesiod.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libhesiod.so.0
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0
        libgssrpc.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgssrpc.so.4
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
        libgpm.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgpm.so.2
        libgpgme.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgpgme.so.11
        libgpgme-pthread.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgpgme-pthread.so.11
        libgpg-error.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0
        libgmpxx.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgmpxx.so.4
        libgmp.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
        libglib-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
        libgio-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0
        libgif.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgif.so.4
        libgdbm.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgdbm.so.2
        libgcrypt.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11
        libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
        libfreetype.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6
        libfreebl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libfreebl3.so
        libfreebl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
        libformw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libformw.so.5
        libform.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libform.so.5
        libfontenc.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libfontenc.so.1
        libfontconfig.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1
        libfipscheck.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libfipscheck.so.1
        libffi.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6
        libe2p.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libe2p.so.2
        libext2fs.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libext2fs.so.2
        libexslt.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libexslt.so.0
        libexpat.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libexpat.so.1
        libelf.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libelf.so.1
        libedit.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libedit.so.0
        libdns.so.81 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libdns.so.81
        libdmraid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdmraid.so.1
        libdmraid.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdmraid.so
        libdmraid-events-isw.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdmraid-events-isw.so.1
        libdmraid-events-isw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdmraid-events-isw.so
        libdl.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libdl.so.2
        libdevmapper.so.1.02 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02
        libdevmapper-event.so.1.02 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
        libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so
        libdevmapper-event-lvm2snapshot.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper-event-lvm2snapshot.so
        libdevmapper-event-lvm2raid.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper-event-lvm2raid.so
        libdevmapper-event-lvm2mirror.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper-event-lvm2mirror.so
        libdevmapper-event-lvm2.so.2.02 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdevmapper-event-lvm2.so.2.02
        libdbus-1.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3
        libdb-4.7.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libdb-4.7.so
        libdb-4.7.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libdb-4.7.so
        libcurl.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
        libcryptsetup.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcryptsetup.so.4
        libcrypto.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10
        libcrypt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1
        libcrack.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcrack.so.2
        libcpupower.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcpupower.so.0
        libcom_err.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2
        libcidn.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libcidn.so.1
        libcap.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcap.so.2
        libcap-ng.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcap-ng.so.0
        libc.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libbz2.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libbz2.so.1
        libblkid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libblkid.so.1
        libbind9.so.80 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libbind9.so.80
        libbfd-2.23.52.0.1-16.47.amzn1.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libbfd-2.23.52.0.1-16.47.amzn1.so
        libauparse.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libauparse.so.0
        libaudit.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libaudit.so.1
        libattr.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libattr.so.1
        libassuan.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libassuan.so.0
        libasound.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libasound.so.2
        libanl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libanl.so.1
        libaio.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libaio.so.1.0.0
        libaio.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libaio.so.1
        libacl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libacl.so.1
        libX11.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6
        libX11-xcb.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1
        libXtst.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXtst.so.6
        libXrender.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1
        libXi.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6
        libXfont.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXfont.so.1
        libXext.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6
        libXau.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6
        libSegFault.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libSegFault.so
        libSM.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6
        libICE.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6
        libBrokenLocale.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.35) => /lib64/libBrokenLocale.so.1
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: I'm confused - when do you see the error, and when is it working perfectly? What is trying to run SQL\*Plus - another script, which maybe resets the environment internally, or runs through su/sudo (and gets a safe environment)?

Comment: @AlexPoole - The steps are  as follows - 1) The instance is being provisioned, at that time scripts run and i write a log. During this period script is supposed to install oracle  xe and then connect to db and create a schema, here i get the error. After completely running the script ,  another script uploads the log to some external location from which i later download , from this log i m seeing the error.    2) After that i log into the instance and check that all the things are working or not.  At that time i see that sqlplus is working properly

Comment: So do you have one script which calls another script to install Oracle XE; and then a separate script that connects to the DB? The environment set-up that is shown in the script in the question (`. /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`) isn't going to have any effect on a parent script/shell, or anything else that runs. You may just need to source that file again before you try to connect to the DB. The question doesn't have the whole picture though; if there's a top-level script that calls what you have shown, can you add that?

Comment: yes, this is what is happening, i have a parent script which is calling another script which installs oracle xe and then there is another script which connect to the DB. i will try what you suggested and then i will let u know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a parent script which calls (but does not source) two child scripts, any environment changes made by the first child script do not affect the parent or the other child.

As a simple example let's say you have an `install.sh` script which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
install_oraclexe.sh
create_schema.sh
```

where `install_oraclexe.sh` contains the commands you showed in step c, including sourcing the environment script with `. /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`; and `create_schema.sh` executes SQL*Plus.

Within `install_oraclexe.sh` the environment is modified and PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc. are available and have values that would allow you to run SQL*Plus later in that same child script. But those environment changes are *only* visible to that script. When it exits and control passes back to the parent script, *its* environment has not been touched, and it is not aware of anything the child has done. When it then executes the `create_schema.sh` script it still doesn't have the Oracle-specfic environment settings, so the second child script doesn't have those either.

You can either move (or copy) the source command for the environment changes to the parent script:

```
#!/bin/bash
install_oraclexe.sh
. /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
create_schema.sh
```

Or perhaps more neatly add it to the `create_schema.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
sqlplus ...
```

Presumably as you are only installing the client you are connecting to a remote DB and are already using a suitable connection string, so you don't need to `export ORACLE_SID=...`.

---

Not really relevant, but extracting files from the XE client installer seems a little odd; I would consider using the easier-to-install [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html) instead. This seems like just the kind of distribution scenario it's designed for.

Comment: thanks for the explanation :) . i needed `imp` command which was not available with the instant client. Does it look like a rational choice ?

Also about doing this way, actually i didnt had the swap space that was required for the installation of `oracle-xe- rpm`. Which is why i chose to do the `cpio` thing using this http://serverfault.com/a/617863/255855   ... again does it seem a rational choice ?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi - ah, I see. If datapump (`impdp`) isn't an option and you're really stuck with the legacy tool (`imp`) then maybe; though I'd perhaps use a silent install rather than extracting files manually. (Except you probably can't do that from the rpm). Presumably this works for you, but not sure if it's a supported mechanism.

Comment: I guess it always comes down to how good your basic concept are ! This worked like charm. I am at  a loss of words to thank you. Seriously i have been trying to solve this for last three days for like 10 hour a day !  Thanks .

Comment: on another note how to use `imp` or some other data dumping command with instant client ?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi - you would need to run the import from the DB server, not the client machine; which may not be practical for you (you'd have to get the dump file there, and have a way to run `impdp` remotely - there is an API so you could do it through SQL\*Plus but I haven't used it)

Comment: a similar issue has cropped up , i m running a command `nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java <some params>`.  it gives me error  `nohup: failed to run command â€˜/bin/javaâ€™: No such file or directory` while provisioning when i am echoing the JAVA_HOME and printing to the log it gives nothing but when i log in to the EC2 instance, it gives me correct values. What can be the possible reason ?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi - i isn't clear where your interactive sessions are getting their environment settings from. If you want your installation script to have the same value, it looks like you need to add that to the `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh` generation in step c; and/or explicitly set it in the parent script, or in a child. Make sure it is exported, wherever it is set.

Comment: No this is not part of the script and is preconfigured in the system before the scripts run.    There is no java related entry in oracle.sh or in any other part of my scripts

Comment: @SubhamTripathi - well no, it doesn't seem to be preconfigured before the scripts run. It may be set for normal users automatically (in /etc/profile or similar), but It may not be set for root, or may not be set at that point in the instance start-up - you could be in a restricted shell, or who knows what. Is it a problem to add it to the script so you know it's set to the value you need?

Comment: OK. This seems logical . I m out of office now.I will check it tomorrow and let u know. Thnx

Comment: Yup, what you said was true. Thanks again